# Why I am getting app icon error while build IOS flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter

While I am debugging flutter IOS app with real device, I always get
" The app icon set "AppIcon" has 46 unassigned children ".
I have been added app icons in the ios> Runner>Assets.xcassets>AppIcon.appiconset .But build failed in xcode. How to fix it.

I described with screen shoots of my project specifications.

[image: This is the error that I got]

[image: Select for iPhone, iPad, CarPlay, Mac, Apple watch]

Comment: Do you add App icons to the main assets and AppIcon Sections? you must add all dimensions that are mentioned in the picture you attached. you can upload a picture(your app icon) with a 1024px dimension to this link and generate all dimension you need.
https://appicon.co/#app-icon after that you can drag and drop to the dimension you need.

Comment: Where is the location of main aassets and AppIcon Sections? I only added app Icons in the directory of "ios> Runner>Assets.xcassets>AppIcon.appiconset". There are many images already have been added, from the 16x16 dimensions image to 1024x1024 dimensions images in that directory.

Comment: as your attached image, your app icons are empty plz, drag and drop the dimensions are mentioned in the pictured you are attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run on either IOS simulator or physical device.
Step -> Delete LauchScreen folder and Asset Catalog Launch name remove in build setting. Then I got it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You must open your iOS folder to Xcode:

[image]

2. goto https://appicon.co/ and drag your icon and generate assets icons:

[image]

3. after download AppIcon.zip you must unzip and drag or copy and paste to the directory:

[image]
[image]

4. paste it to the directory in below picture:

[image]

Comment: I did that way. There are total of 31 images with Content.json file but always show this error. Can't fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package so it will take care of all this issue.

1. please add this dependency on your `pubspec.yaml` page

   dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter
   flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
2. you have to upload an image/icon on your project which you want to see as a launcher icon. (i have created a folder name:image in my project then upload the logo.png in the image folder). Now you have to add the below codes and paste your image path on image_path: in pubspec.yaml page.

   flutter_icons:
   image_path: "images/logo.png"
   android: true
   ios: true
3. Go to terminal and execute this command:

   flutter pub get
4. After executing the command then enter below command:

   flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
5. Done

Comment: i can't know why i cant formate this code.

Comment: I did this procedure as you say. But another two errors get.
First error -> Run from android studio terminal, get
"Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code"
Second error -> Run from Xcode with run button, get
": error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named  "AppIcon".
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */" 
this error. How to solve. How to describe my problems.